# Why is select() not returning in my code?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I need help debugging some code for a multiplayer game with a single server (acting as a master) and multiple clients. I want to connect those multiple clients to the server using the select and FD_Set functions.

Once the client connects to the server, I save their file descriptor in an array and check if data is available on file to read (using select). If yes, read the data, else I want to broadcast a message to all clients. This is run repeatedly in a loop. Every second, I want to broadcast a message to all clients. At the same time, I want to receive data from client too. So I am checking the availabity of data with the help of select function.

Here is my code:

**Server.c:**

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"sys/types.h"
#include"sys/socket.h"
#include"string.h"
#include"netinet/in.h"
#include "sys/select.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PORT 5000
#define BUF_SIZE 2000
#define CLADDR_LEN 100

int arr[4] = { 0 };
char clientAddr[4][CLADDR_LEN];

void main() {
    struct sockaddr_in addr, cl_addr;
    int sockfd, len, ret, newsockfd;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    fd_set fds;
    int maxfd = -1;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        printf("Error creating socket!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Socket created...\n");

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = PORT;

    ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Error binding!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Binding done...\n");

    printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
    listen(sockfd, 4);

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) { //infinite loop
        len = sizeof(cl_addr);
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, &len);
        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            printf("Error accepting connection!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connection accepted...\n");

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(cl_addr.sin_addr), clientAddr[j], CLADDR_LEN);

        arr[j] = newsockfd;
        printf("\n%d", newsockfd);
        //FD_ZERO(&fds);
        //FD_SET(newsockfd, &fds);

    }
    close(sockfd);

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (arr[j] > maxfd)
            maxfd = arr[j];
//      FD_SET(arr[j], &fds);

    //  fcntl(arr[i], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //stop listening for new connections by the main process.
    } //the child will continue to listen.
      //the main process now handles the connected client.

    while (1) {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            FD_SET(arr[i], &fds);
        }

        int returned = select(maxfd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (returned) {
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (FD_ISSET(arr[2], &fds)) {
                    ret = recvfrom(arr[i], (void*) &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0,
                            NULL, NULL);
                    if (ret < 0) {
                        printf("Error receiving data!\n");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    printf("%s", buffer);
                }
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    ret = sendto(arr[j], "abc", BUF_SIZE, 0,
                            (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, len);
                    if (ret < 0) {
                        printf("Error sending data!\n");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    printf("Sent data to %s: %s\n", clientAddr[j], buffer);

                }

    }

    /*while (1) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            memset(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);
            if (FD_ISSET(arr[j], &fds)) {
                ret = recvfrom(arr[j], buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0,
                        (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, &len);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    printf("Error receiving data!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                printf("Received data from %s: %s\n", clientAddr[j], buffer);
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            ret = sendto(arr[j], "abc", BUF_SIZE, 0,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, len);
            if (ret < 0) {
                printf("Error sending data!\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("Sent data to %s: %s\n", clientAddr[j], buffer);

        }
        /* close(arr[0]);
         close[arr[1]);
         close(arr[2]);
         close(arr[3]);
    }*/
}
```

**client.c**:

```
#include"stdio.h"    
#include"stdlib.h"    
#include"sys/types.h"    
#include"sys/socket.h"    
#include"string.h"    
#include"netinet/in.h"    
#include"netdb.h"  

#define PORT 5555  
#define BUF_SIZE 2000   

int main(int argc, char**argv) {    
 struct sockaddr_in addr, cl_addr;    
 int sockfd, ret;    
 char buffer[BUF_SIZE];    
 struct hostent * server;  
 char * serverAddr;  

 if (argc < 2) {  
  printf("usage: client < ip address >\n");  
  exit(1);    
 }  

 serverAddr = argv[1];   

 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);    
 if (sockfd < 0) {    
  printf("Error creating socket!\n");    
  exit(1);    
 }    
 printf("Socket created...\n");     

 memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));    
 addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    
 addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverAddr);  
 addr.sin_port = PORT;       

 ret = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));    
 if (ret < 0) {    
  printf("Error connecting to the server!\n");    
  exit(1);    
 }    
 printf("Connected to the server...\n");    

 memset(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);  
 //printf("Enter your message(s): ");  

 //while (fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {  

 sleep(10);
 ret = sendto(sockfd, "a", BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));    
 if (ret < 0) {    
  printf("Error sending data!\n\t-%s", buffer);    
 }  
 ret = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);    
 if (ret < 0) {    
  printf("Error receiving data!\n");      
 } else {  
  printf("Received: ");  
  fputs(buffer, stdout);  
  printf("\n");  
 }    

 return 0;      
}
```

(The client is passed an IP address.)

This does not work. While debugging the server, it waits at select and nothing is received or sent. What might the problem be?

Comment: You seem to check for `if( FD_ISSET(arr[2]` , but you've never called FD_SET() on the descriptor in `arr[2]`, and you forgot to check FD_ISSET() on arr[0] and arr[1]

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you aren't listening on the right port.  The `sockaddr_in` members needs to be configured in network byte order:

```
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

above is example how select works, in a while loop you must set timeval structure and socket sd

```
 while (1) {

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sd, &readfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (rv == 1) {        
         /*recvfrom*/

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In security firstly FD_ZERO(&readfds)
and you not have to FDSET your clientfds every while loop. You can set one time before the while.

Id u check the client side and clients send data succesfully check the this line 

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (FD_ISSET(arr[2], &fds)) {
                    ret = recvfrom(arr[i], (void*) &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0,
                            NULL, NULL);

In your code FD_ISSET(arr[2], &fds)    you can change the like this

FD_ISSET(arr[i], &fds)   because your for loop do nothing here if you can not change the arr[i]
```